# Facebook login Plugin Integrated cakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I've created a registration page with facebook login facility in cakephp but after login successfully i want to redirect on other page not same page so how can i do it?

facebook plugin : webtechnick/CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin · GitHub

Comment: where do you want be to redirect? other controller or action? can you be more specific? or to external link?

Answer (score 0):

After successfully log in you can use the below method to redirect any of the custom pages:
This documentation is already available in the plugin.

```
function afterFacebookLogin(){
    //Logic to happen after successful facebook login.
     $this->redirect('/custom_facebook_redirect');
}
```

Comment: but where i can write this code because i was written it in appcontroller and my controller also but it's not working...

Comment: i am also use cakephp 2.4

Answer (score 0):

fallow simple login:

```
   if ($this->Auth->login()) {
         return $this->redirect('controller'=>'my_controller', 'action'=>'home_page');
   }
```

[Simple cakephp login](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html)